# SAPUI5 XML-View sap.ui.model.type.Time formatOptions in Model v2

Tags: xml, sapui5

I have a working solution with odata model v1 to display a Edm.Time in my xml view.

Now I am upgrading my model to version 2. Here now comes the problem. 
The same coding in XML view with the new model don´t show any data.

XML-View:

```
{ 
  path:'modelV2>LastCommTime',  
  type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Time',
  formatOptions: {  
    source : {  pattern : '\'PT\'hh\'H\'mm\'M\'ss\'S\'' }, 
    pattern : 'HH:mm:ss'
  }
}
```

This code shows nothing.

If I delete the line `type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Time',` it displays `[object Object]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ODataModel v2 deserializes the Edm.Time in a internal representation. Thats the `[object Object]` you are seeing.

To format it you can use the [sap.ui.model.odata.type.Time](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.type.Time.html) type. A `source.pattern` is not needed in that case:

```
{ 
  path:'modelV2>LastCommTime',  
  type: 'sap.ui.model.odata.type.Time',
  formatOptions: {  
    pattern : 'HH:mm:ss'
  }
}
```